# SQL injection using the value of a parameter as its name

Tags: mysql, sql, jpa

Am I vulnerable to sql injection if I use the the value of parameter as its name?

```
for(String tag : choixalerte.selectedNomExestingtags)
    where += " ach.NOM_ACHTEUR LIKE :" + tag + " or ao.OBJET LIKE :" + tag + "  or lot.INTITULE LIKE :" + tag + "";

// ...

Query native_query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(...);

if(choixalerte.selectedNomExestingtags != null)
    for(String tag : choixalerte.selectedNomExestingtags)
        native_query.setParameter(tag, "%" + tag + "%");
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes. You should not concatenate string in a query.

If you do not want to suffer attack you have some options:

1) Do not concatenate, use "?" instead

2) Sanitize your parameters, you could remove all invalid characters. Remove like # or -- and any other kind of sql commands.

Be aware that you will need to always take a good care in this code because, if a new kind of attack appears you will need to edit the sanitize code.

Comment: but no i don't  just concatenate string i use `:name` to set parameter after like i describe in my question

Comment: what if the parameter name is edited to look like: :#comment_sql ? A hacker could try to manipulate your query.